# (Vanilla JS) Capture the index of an array element with a click event listener?

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener

So I'm making a simple RPG game and I'm intentionally using Vanilla JS because I want to revisit/strengthen some fundamentals. I was able to access  some data of a clicked element, but I specifically would like the index. I'm accessing the child nodes of the target, but want to be able to grab the index. Here my glitch.com link: https://green-cricket.glitch.me/

```
chooseEnemy: function() {
let villiansDiv = document.getElementById('villians-div');
villiansDiv.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let eventClicked = event.target;
  let villianName = event.toElement.childNodes[0].data;
  let children = villiansDiv.children;   

  for (let i = 0; i < villians.length; i++) {
    if (villianName === villians[i].name) {
      views.updateLog('You chose ' +  villians[i].name);
      battleArr.push(villians[i]);
      if (battleArr.length === 1) {
        for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
          children[i].setAttribute('class', 'inactive');
        }
      } else {
          for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            children[i].classList.remove('inactive');
          }
        }
      if (villianName === "Fisherman") {
        let res = villians.splice(0, 1);
        // return;
      }
      else if (villianName === "Farmer") {
        let res = villians.splice(1, 1);
        // return;
      }
      else if (villianName === "Samurai") {
        let res = villians.splice(2, 1);
        // return;
      }
      else if (villianName === "Kuma") {
        let res = villians.splice(3, 1);
        // return;
      }
      else {
        views.updateLog('Click an enemy\'s name');
      }
      // views.updateVillians();
      views.updateChosenEnemy();
    } 
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Why not add the `event listener` directly to the target child elements?

Comment: I could definitely do that. I wanted to try to implement event delegation by adding the event listener to the parent.

 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target